# Tomcat OOM Kill

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory

I have a problem with tomcat. Every once in a while Tomcat get's killed by a oom...

So i tested it with **stressapptest** to force a **oom** and then trying to restart tomcat.

I wrote a simple bash script, that will restart the tomcat service.

This is the Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if  [ "$(systemctl is-active tomcat9)" == "failed" ] || [ "$(systemctl is-active tomcat9)" == "inactive" ]; then
        echo "Restarting tomcat!"
        systemctl restart tomcat9.service
        exit
        else
        exit
fi
```

And inside the setenv.sh i wrote this option.

-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='/root/restart.sh'

This is how the setenv.sh script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:NewSize=1536m -XX:MaxNewSize=1536m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='pkill java;/root/restart.sh' -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -DecadiaConsoleLogLevel=off"
```

But I don't know, why the Option "XX:OnOutOfMemoryError" is not working...

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hopefully you're _not_ running Tomcat as root - but if you execute a script from root's home folder, and it requires root permissions: I'd expect exactly the problems that you have. I'd rather recommend a regular healthcheck, or implement a restart option that doesn't require root permissions by the script. Do not run Tomcat as root...

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer! I also tried to run the script from /etc and changed the permissions to tomcat:tomcat but the script is still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running Tomcat via systemd. That has two consequences:

- Likely the startup command for Tomcat is coming from the systemd configuration instead of the script you edited. So you need to look at other files to make an effective change.
- All you need to tell the JVM is to die on OutOfMemoryErrors. Then tell systemd to automatically restart the service. Your script is not required at all.